# What is the equivalent of a Servlet (Java class that extends HttpServlet in tomcat) in an ASP.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servlets

I started programming my own web applications during the beginning of the Apache Tomcat project, and thus when I am writing a Servlet that responds with some small piece of JSON to some GET or POST my code would look something close to this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.json.*;

public class SimpleServlet_json extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
      json.put("Success", true);
      json.put("Name", request.getParameter("name"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {}
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getOutputStream().print(json.toString());
  }
}
```

My question is **"what is the equivalent method/design/New Item for ASP.net?"**

I have been writing these as WebForms that look like this:

First the (basically empty) `.aspx` file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SimpleServlet_json.aspx.cs" Inherits="com.stackoverflow.question.SimpleServlet_json" %>
```

Then this `.cs` file:

```
namespace com.stackoverflow.question
{
  public partial class SimpleServlet_json : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var json = new JSONResponse()
      {
        Success = Request.QueryString["name"] != null,
        Name = Request.QueryString["name"]
      };
      Response.ContentType = "application/json";
      Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
    }
  }
  [Serializable]
  class JSONResponse
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Success  { get; set; }
  }
}
```

But I secretly worry that I am asking my fellow c# programmers to adopt a non-intuitive style.

These examples are rather contrived, in practice they are used as the JSON representation of a database entity.  For an example the URL `example.com/product/1` is the HTML version (with a JSP or ASPx page associated with the URL) while `example.com/product/1.json` is the JSON representation (with one of these classes).  I'm a fan of URL Rewriting.

Comment: Feel free to gasp in horror and tell me if what I am really asking is "how can I keep writing poorly designed Java in C#"

Comment: Asp.Net/MVC is *far*, *far*, more suited to doing what you are trying to do than WebForms.  It will provide you a method endpoint for each "servlet" (in MVC they will be called actions) and allow you to programatically specify what sort of response it should return (text, HTML, JSON, etc.).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HttpHandlers should do it in any version .NET version after 2003. see this [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478987.aspx).

**However**, a more modern (and more intiutive) approach would be to use .NET MVC or more specifically .NET Web API.

Quote from [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/23/asp-net-web-api-part-1.aspx) on his asp.net blog:

> "Our new ASP.NET Web API support enables you to easily create powerful
>   Web APIs that can be accessed from a broad range of clients (ranging
>   from browsers using JavaScript, to native apps on any mobile/client
>   platform).  It provides the following support:"

And the [official Microsoft .NET Web API page](http://www.asp.net/web-api) states:

> ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP
>   services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers and
>   mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API is an ideal platform for building
>   RESTful applications on the .NET Framework.

Comment: From a quick look I would say not quite.  The servlets in my Tomcat projects and These things, I've been calling Servlets in my ASP.net code share the same space with JSP and ASPx pages respectively.  My examples are rather contrived, in practice they are used as the JSON representation of a database entity (so `example.com/product/1` is the HTML version while `example.com/product/1.json` is the JSON representation)

Comment: Ah i think see where your getting. HttpHandlers should do it. see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478987.aspx

Comment: From the page you linked to: "The ASP.NET page will not contain any code in the .aspx file and will have the same name as your servlet class."  It's comforting to know that I have done on my own what a Microsoft Tool does automatically (what does that make me I wonder)

Comment: I think that makes you p-r-o :) did the link help you or did i misinterpret your question (twice)? Otherwise i'll update my answer accordingly. Not giving up 'til we found a solution :)

Comment: Or a "Microsoft tool" :P if you promote this comment to your answer, maybe with  something like, this is how Microsoft recommends you do something like this however MVC is a much better approach

Comment: Yeah, you should get paid for them using you :) I've updated my answer according to the solution and a mention of Web API in modern developer environments for MVC4 / VS2012 and above.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a `Generic Handler` (.ashx)

```cs
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MyHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext ctx) 
    {
        var json = new JSONResonse()
        {
            Success = ctx.Request.QueryString["name"] != null,
            Name = ctx.Request.QueryString["name"]
        };

        ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        ctx.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerialzeObject(json));
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Make requests to them the same as you would your pages. yoursite.com/my-handler.ashx?name=foo

Comment: That is an interesting approach. I get the feeling Microsoft caught up with this style of development just after VS2008.

Comment: Where every millisecond counts (like for an autocomplete), I still use these low level handlers because they are [high performers](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Sep/04/ASPNET-Frameworks-and-Raw-Throughput-Performance)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question and some research on it ended to Web API. Wanna share with SO.

In the MSDN site,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx

Found a video tutorial where they said that for machine cosumption like iPhone or web app clients of JSON or xml, web API is recommended option. Its around the last part of the video.

While for more complex machine to machine communication WCF is prefereable.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Web-Apps-with-ASP-NET-Jump-Start/Building-Web-Apps-with-ASPNET-Jump-Start-04-Building-a-Service-Layer-with-ASPNET-Web-API

Here is a screenshot from their presentation.

[image]

Comment: My cynicle opinion of WCF is that it wildly complicates the client consumer side for all languages except .net languages. In a pure .net stack I can see the advantages but it's just not a skill that I have spent much time investing in. I prefer my services lean and clear regardless if they are consumed by JavaScript in a browser (or a server) or C# or Python. Basically not my cup of tea, however not everyone is in the same position and this is good infnornation so for that +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't really say i can draw parallels between a Servlet and some type on asp.net, as webforms is quite different.

From your sample code i can recommend that you take a look at asp.net webapi as this will map quite well to what you are currently trying to do.

Comment: This: http://www.asp.net/web-api ? - I have taken a look at it, and as soon as I can get my company to abandon VS2008 and switch to VS2012 I intend to switch a lot of my code to that.

Answer (score 1):

More like Owin

'OWIN defines a standard interface between .NET web servers and web applications.'